# Simple matlab issue with a matrices

Tags: matlab

Im using matlab for the first time and im trying to input this matrix:

[image: this is the matrix i need to enter onto matlab]

im using petercorke toolbox

can anyone help please 
i know it must be obvious but im drawing a blank

Comment: You really need to say something here... Also, why do you have an exclamation mark?

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/creating-and-concatenating-matrices.html

Answer (score 2):

You should start using the Matlab Documentation-there you can find all the basics!

[Creating matrices in Matlab](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/math/creating-and-concatenating-matrices.html#f1-84906)

```
A=[-0.7071 0 -0.7071; -0.7071 0 0.7071; 0 1 0];
```